# SQL - Counting from 2 or more Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am somehow new to SQL, and I have a Election Application. I have done 80% of it and now stuck at counting votes from 2 or more Columns.

Example Table:

```
|**Senator_1** | **Senator_2** | **Senator_3**|
----------------------------------------------
   George      |    Carl       |   Anthony
   Carl        |    Tony       |   Stark
   Anthony     |    George     |   Tony
   Anthony     |    George     |   Stark
```

I would like to have this kind of result.

```
|**Candidate_Name** | **Vote_Count**|
-------------------------------------
   George           |   3
   Anthony          |   3
   Carl             |   2
   Stark            |   2
   Tony             |   2
```

I really don't have any idea of what query I am going to use. Any ideas of solving this?

By the way, for the confusion and all the arguments that started here, I am going to explain:

I wanted to be straight to my problem that's why I just posted a sample table. I have a table for the Voters, Candidates and the Votes. All tables have its ID and such, so I'm pretty sure it's normalized.

Comment: What the heck am I looking at?  What does that data in the first table represent?

Comment: Even without knowing, I can tell you right off the bat, you've got some major design flaws in your data.

Comment: @StevenMoseley My guess would be that every vote is a vote for 3 candidates and he wants to count the total votes per candidate.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, it should be four tables.... one representing `voters`, one for `votes` one representing `vote_candidates` (many to many), and finally, a table for `candidates`

Comment: Put your table at least to the 2-nd normal form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main issue that you have is your table is not normalized. I would strongly advise that you fix your current table structure. A *possible* new table structure would be:

```
/* Table for unique voters */
CREATE TABLE voters (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/* Table for unique candidates */
CREATE TABLE candidates (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/* Many-to-many table storing votes by voters for candidates */
CREATE TABLE votes (
    voter_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    candidate_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (voter_id, candidate_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (voter_id) REFERENCES voters (id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (candidate_id) REFERENCES candidates (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/* Populate data */
INSERT INTO voters (name)
VALUES ('Voter 1'), ('Voter 2'), ('Voter 3'), ('Voter 4');

INSERT INTO candidates (name)
VALUES ('George'), ('Carl'), ('Anthony'), ('Tony'), ('Stark');

INSERT INTO votes (voter_id, candidate_id)
VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3),
       (2,2), (2,4), (2,5),
       (3,3), (3,1), (3,4),
       (4,3), (4,1), (4,5);
```

Then you could easily get a result by joining the two tables:

```
/* query showing all voters and the candidates they voted for */
SELECT voters.name, candidates.name
FROM votes
    INNER JOIN voters on votes.voter_id = voters.id
    INNER JOIN candidates ON votes.candidate_id = candidates.id;

/* Finally, a query showing votes per candidate */
SELECT candidates.name, COUNT(*) AS votes
FROM votes
    INNER JOIN candidates ON votes.candidate_id = candidates.id
GROUP BY candidates.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002d6/2)

However, if you cannot alter the design of the table, then you can get the result by unpivoting the data that you have in multiple columns.  You can use a UNION ALL to unpivot the multiple columns into rows to get the count:

```
select name, count(*) TotalVotes
from
(
  select senator_1 name
  from yt
  union all
  select senator_2 name
  from yt
  union all
  select senator_3 name
  from yt
) d
group by name
order by totalVotes desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dbca7/4)

Comment: Undid my -1, but it's still not good to perpetuate bad design.

Comment: @StevenMoseley I agree that the ideal solution would be to correct the table structure.  This is a solution to their existing problem.

Comment: @StevenMoseley That is totally your decision not to +1 it. I am offering up a solution to their problem, note I have also advised them to alter their design and am in the process of writing up an alternate design solution.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Feel free to critique my edit, if you had given a minute before criticizing my initial answer you would have seen that I was planning on adding a possible new design to the OP.  I typically expand on my answers, especially when I see that the user has issues with a design.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Guy, sometimes the schema is fixed, and users are stuck with it and can't just rebuild the entire application at the whim of some know-it-all on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Point taken.  PS - merged my answer into this one, as they had become too similar to leave separate.  Also, +1 and apologies to bluefeet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to count the total no. of occurrence of each name in different columns. Based on this, I think something like below might help -

```
select senator, sum(cnt) as 'count' from (
select senator_1 as 'senator', count(1) 'cnt' from election_table group by senator_1
union all
select senator_2 as 'senator', count(1) 'cnt' from election_table group by senator_2
union all
select senator_3 as 'senator', count(1) 'cnt' from election_table group by senator_3
) x group by x.senator
```